# I'm getting heroku node errors while deploying the mern app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrIKL.png)

I'm trying to deploy my mern app to heroku but again and again its failing i've posted the error using the image url above. Looks like some kind of node error

Comment: Post your errors in code blocks,avoid using image links

Answer (score 0):

if you using heroku the error is not because of image you should use heroku cli
heroku log tail-- comment
to show you the exact problem I think the problem is because of your keys or database
that you should add.
I had this error and the only way was adding my mongo url cluster as a key in my heroku app.

Comment: node:internal\modules\cjs\loader:936 <--when i run heroku log tail-- this is the first error i get how can i fix it ?